# Title field in SharePoint document library

Tags: search, title

we have a problem with our search, our search is using Title field to find the documents and sometimes users use template which already have title name and is different from document Name, how can i make title field same as Name field.
Regards

Comment: Is this an end user search, typing into the search box, or via code or web service? Are you using Managed Properties like "title"?  ( title:myKeyWord )

Comment: this is just a normal search from end user, we do use manage properties